# Template argument type exclusion: Would this make for a useful C++ feature?

Tags: c++, compiler, language-features, templates

When using templates we can have `T` be any type upon class instantiation. If `T` is a specific type that needs to be handled differently or in a special way we can *specialize* or *partial specialize* that `class template`.

What if we want `T` to be any type except for specific types that we don't want it to allow?

With this in mind, I was thinking of making use of either the `!` or `!=` operator(s) or more as them being tokens within this context as far as the compiler(s) would be concerned to prevent the `class template` from using that type...

Here's an example of what the syntax would look like:

```
template<typename T, T !=char, T !=unsigned char>
// or 
template<typename T, T !char, T !unsigned char>
// This means that T can be anything but char and unsigned char!
struct Foo {
    T value;
};
```

Then:

```
Foo<int> f1;   // Okay
Foo<float> f2; // Okay
Foo<char> f3;  // Would fail to compile generating the appropriate error message or 
               // would just delete that instance as if it was never declared
               // and generate compiler errors for all code that would try to use it.
```

This could also be extended or expanded to work with *user-defined* `types` as well...

I believe that this could allow for simplifying a lot of code allowing the programmer to explicitly fine-tune and restrict their code usage to their users, that it is easy to read with direct intent shown, and that it would be fairly easy for the compilers to implement without breaking already existing code bases by adding in this feature.

Would this be something that you would find useful and practical?

Comment: +1 for a good question (though I don't think it is a good idea).

Comment: This is what the [type trait `enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) is for (especially when combined with operator `!`).  There is already plenty of code that uses this technique - you can easily find it and learn the many ways to use it. In fact, [check this tutorial out](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/enable-if).

Comment: @DocBrown That's why I post them here because they are only concepts. It's to gain insight from the community at large to see the pros and cons of possible concepts.

Comment: @davidbak I already know about `enable_if` in `<type_trait>`. I was just asking about the concept of streamlining or automating that process within the template's argument list declaration.

Comment: @FrancisCugler: "*Would this make for a useful C++ feature?*" No SE site is a viable forum for questions of this nature. There are other outlets available if you want to discuss whether a particular C++ language feature would be good or not.

Comment: @DocBrown here's another concept that I was thinking of... we already have the `->()` operator as this is used on pointers to get member objects... we have move semantics with the use of `stl`, `boost`, or other provided libraries APIs. What if we added move semantics into an operator? Something like;  `int a = 5; int b = 7; a <- b;` This would not copy but move `b` into `a`...

Comment: @NicolBolas This is a Q/A for Software Engineering, doesn't compiler design, language features fall under that category?

Comment: If you already know about `enable_if` then my answer is: Use that.  It's completely adequate.  You can use it with operator `!` too.  This added syntax you suggest is, IMO, only helpful to express what is already a marginal case somewhat easier than you already can do it perfectly well, and when there is _so much else_ I'd much rather see in the language that I'm not going to see because C++ syntax is _rarely_ extended and only then with _great_ difficulty, I'm not fussed about the lack of this improvement.  (Examples of what I'd like to see: user-defined operators, infix-function syntax ...)

Comment: @davidbak I completely agree with user-defined operators!

Comment: @NicolBolas: I think it very case dependent if questions about potential new language features are acceptable for this site. They are definitely not off-topic, but there is always a certain risk for them to be too opinionated or open ended. In this case, however, I think the question can be answered in a straightforward way why the suggested feature is not as good as it might look at a first glance. Hence I don't see any reason to refuse it.

Comment: @NicolBolas Very on point with your comment to Doc Brown... My question was directed and to the point with a solid example with expectations. I was looking for both + and - criticism to see if it had any potential. If you don't ask people who use the tools daily, you'll never know! One of my teachers from many years ago said, "There is no such thing as a dumb question. It is always up for interpretation to gain a better understanding into something that it might become useful information."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would it make sense to forbid *specificially named types* in template parameters (without a template specialization)? The only real reason I can imagine is that the forbidden type would cause some issues in the template, probably some issues the compiler cannot determine directly. For example, `char` might not be used, because its range is not large enough for the specific purpose, but that would only reveal itself at runtime.

However, this kind of check can too easily become pointless when the forbidden type is wrapped inside in another type, like

```
struct Bar{ char MyChar; }
```

which has essentially the same type traits as `char`. So the same reasons for using `char` as a parameter would apply to `Bar` as well, but the type exclusion would not catch it.

Hence, I think it would make a lot more sense to check the required type traits directly for finding out if a certain type is suitable for usage in a template or not. This would be also way more readable, since it shows more clearly **why** a certain type shall be not allowed. For this, the suggested syntax would be not not sufficient, a `static_assert` together with using tools from `<type_traits>` makes IMHO more sense.

Comment: I like the way you expressed your position and point of view. It portrays a sense of negative criticism in a positive way, instead of negative criticism in a negative way. Very informative instead of just stating that it can be done in another way. You clearly explain why the existing functionality is a better approach and describing where you could encounter the unforeseen drawbacks that would cause it to fail, leading to future problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can already do this, with a `static_assert` in your template.

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    // This means that T can be anything but char and unsigned char!
    static_assert(!std::is_same_v<T, char>);
    static_assert(!std::is_same_v<T, unsigned char>);
    T value;
};
```

Comment: Yes, but what looks easier to read and cleaner? What uses less code or instructions? Not having to include the library for `std::is_same<T>`... I'm looking at code simplification just by allowing the declaration of the template itself to handle this for you upon compilation just by incorporating the use of the `!` or `!=` operators on that argument type `<T>`. You also wouldn't have `static_assert` cluttering the declaration of your class template... faster compile times...

Comment: @FrancisCugler This is much more flexible, you can have any constexpr bool in the assert

Comment: I'm not saying to do away with `static_assert` and `is_same`... but to "streamline" this process by providing it as a built-in feature upon compilation & class template instantiation... Making it an alternative, and another useful tool.

Comment: @FrancisCugler there is no runtime overhead here, it's all evaluate at compile time. Also, why add even more confusing syntax to a language when the stdlib can express the same concepts and even more concepts better? If you have to exclude types from templates so often that you'll benefit from the conciseness i guess you're sort of on the wrong track.

Comment: @marstato I never mentioned anything about runtime, or build times, I explicitly stated compile time within my previous comment. And exactly how is the syntax more confusing? It's quite expressive with direct intent and meaning!

Comment: @FrancisCugler - the C++ language designers - and many many C++ users - have a philosophy of what gets added - syntax-wise especially, but also as standard libraries - to an already complex language, and what gets left out.  Except for _concepts_, mostly everything to do with template syntax is just the way it is, and it is all accepted.  Yes, metaprogramming with template syntax is baroque, at best, but that's the language we've got and the language we're going to have.  _Concepts_, though, added in C++20, are a major change for the better - and it took well over a decade to get it in ...

Comment: @davidbak That's part of my point. C++ is a very powerful language with many rich features and I prefer it over most. I'd like to push the envelope further by trying to simplify a lot of the "cryptic" syntax that comes with templates. If you never use them C++ is one of the easiest languages. When you do with their current state, many extra hours to get the syntax correct, and that much more trying to compile, build, and debug. If we simplify their syntax and add in self-explanatory features to automate things, the more expressive your code can be and written much faster, easier to debug.

Comment: You don't make language features less complex by adding more language features to them. Concepts are both concise and *general*, which is one of the main reasons they were added